# How to prevent a second dialog box from closing one opened earlier

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am a Fortran programmer but now have to maintain a GUI written in Tcl/Tk that drives the Fortran code (communicating with it through a socket), but I have very limited knowledge of tcl.

My fortran program sends XML to the GUI about an error condition and this is displayed in a dialogue box using the code shown below:

```
body Processingwizard::updateProcessingData { a_param_class a_dom } {

    # Check on status of task
    set status_code [$a_dom selectNodes string(/integration_postrefinement/status/code)]
    if {$status_code == "error"} {
    .m confirm \
        -title "Error" \
        -type "1button" \
        -text "Integration post-refinement failed, sorry.\n[$a_dom selectNodes string(/integration_postrefinement/status/message)]" \
        -button1of1 "Dismiss"
    } else {
....
```

Where confirm is defined as:

```
body Dialog::confirm {} {
    centreOnScreen
    wm deiconify $itk_component(hull)
    raise $itk_component(hull)
    grabber set $itk_component(hull)
    #bind $itk_component(hull) <ButtonRelease-1> [list raise $itk_component(hull)]
    tkwait variable [scope responses($this)]
    #bind $itk_component(hull) <ButtonRelease-1> { }
    grabber release $itk_component(hull)
    wm withdraw $itk_component(hull)
    return $responses($this)
}
```

The problem I am having is that, as a result of other XML that is sent to the GUI, it is opening another dialogue box with different warning message and opening the second dialogue box closes the first one so the user does not get to see the first warning. The second dialogue box is opened using the code below.

Is there a way that I can stop the first dialogue box being closed unless the user has actually pressed the "Dismiss" button? I thought the "tkwait" in the method "confirm" might do this, but it does not.

```
# Warn the user
.m configure \
    -type "3button" \
    -title "Doubtful refinement" \
    -text "The following parameters have refined to physically questionable values:\n\n$messages\" \
    -button1of3 "Reset" \
    -button2of3 "Always" \
    -button3of3 "Once" \
    -buttontext "Ignore (in this Session only)        "
set choice [.m confirm]
if {$choice == 2} {
    resetDetectorCrystalParams
} elseif {$choice == 1} {
    set alwaysignore 0
} else {
    set alwaysignore 1
}
```

Comment: It's probably because you're using the same window name `.m`. If you pick a different name, or better dynamically generate a name, you should be able to see both dialogs.

Comment: Sorry, how do I set a different window name?

Comment: use something different from `.m`  for one of the dialogs

Comment: OK, I'm afraid that I'm really not familiar with tcl, should ".m" have been defined somewhere in the tcl code (I can't find it by grepping). If I can find how ".m" has been set up I can use that as an example to set up a new window name.

Comment: OK, I have now found the declaration for ".m" (Message .m) in another part of the tcl code, hopefully I can now set up a new window.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for your help

Comment: As it stands, this question does not have much value for other readers. You could add your own answer explaining how you solved the problem and make it the accepted answer, or you could delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by glenn jackman, the issue was that I was using the same window name (.m) for the two different error messages. I simply changed the window name for the second error message ( to .n) and declared this (Message .n) and changed the line:

set choice [.m confirm]

to:

set choice [.n confirm]

in the code for the second error message and the problem was solved.